# Automate the Boring Stuff with Python The Collatz Sequence assignment repet

Tags: python, collatz

I know there are a lot of posts on this assignment and they all have great information, however, I am trying to take my assignment to the next level. I have written the code for the sequence, I have written the try and except functions and have added the continues so the program will keep asking for a positive integer till it gets a number. now I would like the whole program to repeat indefinitely, and I will then write a (Q)uit option. I tried making the question ask into a global scope but that was wrong, can someone please give me a hint and I will keep working on it. here is my code;

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        result = 3 * number + 1
        return result
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Give me a positive number: "))
        if n <= 0:
            continue
        break
    except ValueError:
        continue
while n != 1:
    n = collatz(int(n))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. SO is not a code-writing service, but if you post your best attempt, we can help you fix it. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) and [ask] more generally. **Edit** On second thought, it's not too much effort. I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of repeating indefinitely is as follows.

```
def collatz(number):
     " No element of Collatz can be simplified to this one liner "
    return 3 * number + 1 if number % 2 else number // 2

while True:
    # Will loop indefinitely until q is entered
    try:
        n = input("Give me a positive number: ")
        # String returned from input
        if n.lower() == "q":  # check for quit (i.e. q)
            break
        else:
            n = int(n)        # assume int, so convert (will jump to exception if not)

            while n > 1:      # loops and prints through collatz sequence
                n = collatz(n)
                print(n)

    except ValueError:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all you need to do is move the second `while` loop into the first and add a "quit" option, though I've done some additional things here to simplify your code and give more feedback to the user.

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        # Removed "print" here - should be done in the calling scope
        return number // 2
    else:  # Removed "elif" - You already know "number" is not divisible by two
        return 3 * number + 1

while True:
    s = input("Give me a positive number, or 'q' to quit: ")
    if s == 'q':
        print('Quit')
        break

    try:
        # Put as little code as possible in a "try" block
        n = int(s)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number, try again")
        continue

    if n <= 0:
        print("Number must be greater than 0")
        continue

    print(n)
    while n != 1:
        n = collatz(n)
        print(n)
```

Example run:

```
Give me a positive number, or 'q' to quit: a
Invalid number, try again
Give me a positive number, or 'q' to quit: 0
Number must be greater than 0
Give me a positive number, or 'q' to quit: 2
2
1
Give me a positive number, or 'q' to quit: 3
3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
Give me a positive number, or 'q' to quit: q
Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you the suggestions are great!! Here is my finished code;

```
    def collatz(number):
  while number != 1:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number // 2
        print(number)
    else:
        number = 3 * number + 1
        print(number)
while True:
    try:
        n = input("Give me a positive number or (q)uit: ")
        if n == "q":
            print('Quit')
            break
        n = int(n)    
    except ValueError:
        continue
    collatz (n)
```